# How to route particular select query on master in pgpool 3 postgres...?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgpool

My query is, how to route particular select query on a master in `pgpool`. I have tried black_function_list parameter in `pgpool.conf` but that did not work out.

Also, my `pgpool` mode is **streaming and load balancing is on**.

Comment: I am not sure, but You can visit this url. May be you will get your solution. http://pgsqlpgpool.blogspot.in/2016/06/avoiding-connection-failure-while.html

Answer (score 1):

pgpool's black_function_list parameter only works with functions. For other queries you can use /*NO LOAD BALANCE*/ prefix comment in the query string to make sure it should land on the master PostgreSQL node.

```
For example    
postgres=#/*NO LOAD BALANCE*/ SELECT * from abc;
```